# Debouncing search input onChangeText()

Tags: react-native, lodash, debouncing

Using lodash's `debounce()`, I'm trying to wait 1.2 seconds before setting a search term in my app's state. But it doesn't seem to run my function when I use it:

```
onChangeText(text) {
    console.log('setting');
    setSearching(true);
    setSearchTerm(text);
}
render(){
    return(
        <TextInput style={s.input}
            onChangeText={() => {
                _.debounce(this.onChangeText, 1200);
                /*
                doing just...
                this.onChangeText(text)
                ...works
                */
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

I do not get `setting` in my console log when using `debounce`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you're creating a new instance of `debounce` on every call of the handler.

Ideally, you should wrap your entire handler in `debounce` since debounce *creates a `debounced` function that delays invoking `func`*

```
onChangeText={_.debounce(this.onChangeText, 1200)}
```

Comment: This works, but how can I call `setSearching(true);` before the debounce?

Comment: Not sure but you might need to use `debounce` inside the function just for `setSearchTerm` function `_.debounce(() => searchTerm(text), 1200)`